# How to implement nonblocking event loop in Duktape?

Tags: javascript, embedded, esp32, duktape

I'm embedding Duktape into esp32 which runs FreeRTOS.

And I'm stuck with implementing a nonblocking event loop.

As I understood it is pretty trivial to implement an event loop in terms of async-yield. But it is not very nice because it will always load a CPU even if there is nothing really happening except for waiting for the event to occur.
I'm thinking about adding another Duktape thread to a Duktape heap where my application is running. And make this separate Duktape thread run by another RTOS task with mutex as sync.

But also there is written that this can lead to issues with garbage collection.

And also as I understand, I will need to take mutex in every native C function that is bound to js functions inside the heap, and that is a little bit inconvenient.

Maybe I miss some simpler way to create such an event loop?

What I need event loop for: execute callback for GUI and run timers. But I need it to sleep when nothing is to do.

Comment: If there are pending timers, but nothing else to do in a particular loop run then you could yield the loop's CPU share back to the OS for other work. I believe all platform schedulers support some kind of yield.

Comment: Yeah, I can make task sleep, but I don't quite understand how to implement this stuff. Because i need to sleep the task in which app actually was executed initially, which runs the Duktape. And yield is Duktape yield, not a native. Like there are two js functions that execute in single native thread, alternating each other with yield statements. But how to bring this concept out of the Duktape and be able to yield to some C function that will sleep the task, I don't understand.

Comment: Implement the runloop in the hosting application, which then can call out to the system's scheduler.

Comment: what do you mean? why call system's scheduler? i already run Duktape in a freertos task.

Comment: Of course it's up to the OS how you yield execution to another thread/process. In Windows, for example, there is [SwitchToThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-switchtothread?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to do that.

Comment: but how it is related to my question?